I have set of CSV files landing into BLOB storage, I need to convert them into parquet format to a single file
How to convert multiple .csv files those are currently is in Azure BLOB storage into Parquet format into an another BLOB also into a single file, I need union the csv files as all files has similar structure.
I am working in ADF environment

You can use Copy activity to achieve your requirement.
Create source and target datasets of delimited text and parquet type and the linked services for these should be your source and target blob storages respectively. In the source dataset, give the path till root container only.

In the target dataset, give your target location and the target filename as your wish.

Give these two datasets to the copy activity. In the copy activity source use wild card file path *.csv like below.

You can use wild card path for the folders or give folders name manually as per the folder level of the files. Here, my csv files are inside the uniondata container, so I have given the path only till that.
In the copy activity target, select Merge files option.

Now, debug the pipeline and a single parquet file with a given name will be generated in the target location like below.

This file will contain the union of all the source files but note that the order of the rows will be random.
